# Comparing passwords in php

Tags: php, mysql, md5, strcmp

I have this following if-case, but I can't get it to work properly.

I have a database that stores `md5` encrypted passwords as varchar.

I let the user enter his/her password and username in a form and send it to php the normal way.

```
$nickName = $_POST['User']; 
$pass = $_POST['Pass']; 

[...]  

$value = mysql_fetch_array($result);    

//i assume strcmp returning 0
if(!(strcmp($value,md5($pass)))) {
   echo "Willkommen, " . $nickName;         
} else {
   echo "Passwoerter stimmen nicht ueberein!";              
}
```

Let me add the fact I also tried out various statements like 
`if(strcmp($value,md5($pass)) == 0)` and `$value == md5($pass)`.

My clue is I have to cast the from `$value` returned value somehow. Maybe something like a parseInt (afaik md5 is Integer) to change the value I got from the database to int.

Comment: You should not be storing passwords as MD5, you should be using bcrypt. Also MD5 is not integer, it's a hex string.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array, does what it says fetches an array, you are trying to do a string compare on an array you probably want something like `$value['password']`

Comment: @PatrickEvans post that as an answer. that's exactly right.

Comment: I agree with cryptic, you shouldnt be storing passwords in md5. But your question is vague regardless. How are you spring your passwords? Your not referencing the field correctly, etc

Comment: Muchas gracias to you sir, you just opened my eyes. If you write an answere i will check it as "solved" @ patrick evans

Comment: First off MD5 is a hashing algorithm not encryption. Second if you are going to use hashing for storing your passwords at least use SHA-2 which is much more safe hashing algorithm.

Comment: @Jason you should never use SHA-2 either. The whole reason we don't use such algorithms is that they use little computing power to generate the hash, which makes them fast. Fast is not good when it comes to security because a computer can generate rainbow tables quite quickly for them. Bcrypt is a much slower way to generate a hash so it's more secure. You can even set a cost option to make it even slower if you're extra paranoid.

Comment: That's why I said "If you are going to use a hashing algorithm". I don't recommend it either. Especially without some kind of salting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array), does what it says fetches an array, you are trying to do a string compare on an array you probably want something like $value['password']

```
if(!(strcmp($value['password'],md5($pass)))) 
{
   echo "Willkommen, " . $nickName;            
}
else 
{
   echo "Passwoerter stimmen nicht ueberein!";             
}
```

and of course think about using mysqli as mysql is deprecated

Comment: downvoted because someone felt uncomfortable with my spelling... however as I am not english I think I made myself clear

Answer (score 0):

I am having a tough time understanding what you want to do and I'm afraid I can't add a comment so ill try and help as much as I can.

Basically I thino you are trying to perform some sort of authentication??? If so what you should do is query the database by the username for example:

```
$var = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select userid, userpass from users where username = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["User"]));
```

Then you can check their pass input with what's in the database:

```
if (md5($_POST["Pass"]) == $var["userpass"])
{
    //go ahead and continue on
}
else
{
    //they must have messed up so don't pass go
}
```

I hope this is what you wish to do and sorry if I got it comppetely wrong!!!

Comment: Not a problem, I just wasn't sure if I understood what you wanted. Good luck :)